# RTSP/TRMP Video call Applicaton ringing indicator android

Tags: android, callback, video-streaming, rtsp, rtmp

I am developing an Android application for video calling using RTSP/TRMP and LibStreaming. When i initiate a call from my app, i cant able to understand thether the other end is ringing / attend my call. 
I would like to know how to set a ringback tone for an outgoing call. I need to play it till the other user attend the call or reject the call

Answer (score 0):

For video calling, you can use [WebRTC](https://webrtc.org/native-code/android/). its good library

you can check [demo](https://github.com/GleasonK/AndroidRTC)

Using RTSP, it will difficulty for you. if you want one way live steaming then RTSP is fine